# How to retrive value of Hidden Field in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
Image     |    ID (Hidden)  |  First Name   | Last Name ......
2231231        1               ABC             DEF 
2122342         2               ADED            SAD
```

Model Class: for this scenario which i use.

```
 public partial class tbl_User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get ID field value i used the following code which through Null Reference Error -->

```
 private void userdatagrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataRowView rowview = userdatagrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
         value = rowview.Row["ID"].ToString();
```

//Second Method

```
 string ID = (userdatagrid.SelectedItem as tbl_User).ID.ToString(); 
    }
```

//Double Click Event

```
private void btnedit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataRowView rowview = userdatagrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            string id = rowview.Row[0].ToString();
            UpdateDetial ud = new UpdateDetial(int.Parse(value));
            ud.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `userdatagrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView`, `userdatagrid.SelectedItem as tbl_User`?? exactly what is the class `userdatagrid` row binding to? Can you post that?

Comment: Its blinding with tbl_User Class

Comment: If it is, `(userdatagrid.SelectedItem as tbl_User).ID` will return ID value, unless `selectedIndex = -1`

Answer (score 0):

```
string ID = ((DataRowView)userdatagrid.SelectedItem).Row["id"].ToString();
```

or

```
var data = (DataRowView)userdatagrid.SelectedItem;
var userId = data.Row["id"];
```

Comment: What is this? Question is about WPF, not ASP.NET

Comment: Both Solution throw Null Reference Exception

Comment: try to change the "id" to "ID"

Comment: This Error Shows: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`14[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Byte[],System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have such a model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can get hidden value of column by using `SelectedItem` property in `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
   {
      var data = (Person)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
      var userID = data.ID;
   }
}
```

Comment: Its throw Null Reference Exception